# Chrome Driver Cannot Get Cookies?

Tags: python

I'm using selenium with the chrome driver to attempt to get some cookies from google my code:

```
import json
from selenium import webdriver
import time

taskID = input("Choose task: ")

driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=accountsettings&passive=1209600&osid=1&continue=https://myaccount.google.com/intro&followup=https://myaccount.google.com/intro")
while "sign" in driver.current_url:
    continue
driver.quit()
gcooks = driver.get_cookies()
with open('cookies'+str(taskID)+'.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(gcooks, outfile,indent=4)
```

However it returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cookieinjector.py", line 12, in <module>
    gcooks = driver.get_cookies()
  File "C:\Users\ninja_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 825, in get_cookies
    return self.execute(Command.GET_ALL_COOKIES)['value']
  File "C:\Users\ninja_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 310, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "C:\Users\ninja_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 466, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "C:\Users\ninja_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 490, in _request
    resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\ninja_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\ninja_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\ninja_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 258, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Users\ninja_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Something to do with the chromedriver being broken on the version I'm using, Firefox works a lot better

Answer (score 0):

some cookies can not retrieve *Selenium*. I assume that this is *HTTPonly* cookies. You can solve the problem by retrieving and decrypting the cookies from the *"/Default/Cookies"* file via sqlite3. So far I have only found a way to do this for Linux and Windows. It works with *Google Chrome* and *Chromium*.

```
import sqlite3
import sys
from os import getenv, path
import os
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Protocol.KDF import PBKDF2
import keyring

def get_cookies(url, cookiesfile):

    def chrome_decrypt(encrypted_value, key=None):
        dec = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV=iv).decrypt(encrypted_value[3:])
        decrypted = dec[:-dec[-1]].decode('utf8')
        return decrypted

    cookies = []
    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        import win32crypt
        conn = sqlite3.connect(cookiesfile)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(
            'SELECT name, value, encrypted_value FROM cookies WHERE host_key == "' + url + '"')
        for name, value, encrypted_value in cursor.fetchall():
            if value or (encrypted_value[:3] == b'v10'):
                cookies.append((name, value))
            else:
                decrypted_value = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(
                    encrypted_value, None, None, None, 0)[1].decode('utf-8') or 'ERROR'
                cookies.append((name, decrypted_value))

    elif sys.platform == 'linux':
        my_pass = 'peanuts'.encode('utf8')
        iterations = 1
        key = PBKDF2(my_pass, salt, length, iterations)
        conn = sqlite3.connect(cookiesfile)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(
            'SELECT name, value, encrypted_value FROM cookies WHERE host_key == "' + url + '"')
        for name, value, encrypted_value in cursor.fetchall():
            decrypted_tuple = (name, chrome_decrypt(encrypted_value, key=key))
            cookies.append(decrypted_tuple)
    else:
        print('This tool is only supported by linux and Mac')

    conn.close()
    return cookies


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
else:
    salt = b'saltysalt'
    iv = b' ' * 16
    length = 16

#get_cookies('YOUR URL FROM THE COOKIES', 'YOUR PATH TO THE "/Default/Cookies" DATA')
```